# how should I override the string

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to write this code from its test file.

```
public class MineNeighbourTest
{
    private MineWorld world; 
    private Position  position;
    private MineNeighbour neighbour;
    private MineNeighbour bigNeighbour;

    /**
     * Default constructor for the test class.
     */
    public MineNeighbourTest()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Sets up the test fixture.
     *
     * Called before every test case method.
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        world    = new MineWorld(6, 6);
        position = new Position(world, 3, 1); 
        // create a field that has 4 mines in the neighbourhood 
        neighbour    = new MineNeighbour(position, 4);
        // create a field that has 8 mines in the neighbourhood
        bigNeighbour = new MineNeighbour(position, 8);
    }

    /**
     * Tears down the test fixture.
     *
     * Called after every test case method.
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
        world        = null;
        position     = null;       
        neighbour    = null;
        bigNeighbour = null;
    }


    /**
     * Test of getNeighbouringMines method, of class MineNeighbour.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetNeighbouringMines() 
    {
        assertEquals(4, neighbour.getNumNeighbouringMines());
        assertEquals(8, bigNeighbour.getNumNeighbouringMines());
    }


    /**
     * Test of getStringRepresentation method, of class MineNeighbour.
     */
    @Test    
    public void testGetStringRepresentation() 
    {
        assertEquals("4", neighbour.getStringRepresentation());
        assertEquals("8", bigNeighbour.getStringRepresentation());
    }    

}
```

here is what i wrote:

```
public class MineNeighbour extends Occupant
{
    private Position pos; 

    public MineNeighbour(Position neighbour, Position bigNeighbour) { 
        super(neighbour);
    } 
    public Position getNeighbouringMines() { 
        return neighbour; 
        return bigNeighbour; 
    }
    @Override
    public String getStringRepresenation() { 
        return getNeighbouringMines();
    }
}
```

I need to overwrite `getStringRepresentation()` to 4&8 with the additional fields of `neighbour` and `bigNeighbour`, I don't quite understand the information given to me by `MineNeighbourTest`.

My occupant class:

```
public class Occupant
{

    private Position pos;

    public Occupant(Position iniPos) { 
        this.pos = iniPos; 
    } 

    public Position getPosition() { 
        return pos; 
    } 

    public void setPosition(Position newPos) { 
        this.pos = newPos; 
    } 

    public String getStringRepresentation() { 
        return " "; 
    }
```

}

Comment: Does that code even compile? You have one method with two returns, and this simply cannot be. Can you clarify your problem? It's confusing, at least to me.

Comment: I'm not understanding this, your `getNeighborouringMines()` method has two return statements right after another?

Comment: Noo, I'm not sure about how I need to declare my method and override getStringRepresenation. I think what the test file asked me to do is to create two additional fields neighbour and bigNeighbour.

Comment: I'm supposed to use the MineNeighbourTest to finish my code in class MineNeighbour but I don't quite understand the test file.

Comment: Well without really knowing what Occupant does, `super(neighbour)` doesn't make much sense to me. And, I think you need to work on getting your MineNeighbour working first before you try anymore tests. It doesn't look like it would behave like you expect.

Comment: public class Occupant
{
    
    private Position pos;
    
    public Occupant(Position iniPos) { 
        this.pos = iniPos; 
    } 
    
    public Position getPosition() { 
        return pos; 
    } 
    
    public void setPosition(Position newPos) { 
        this.pos = newPos; 
    } 
    
    public String getStringRepresentation() { 
        return " "; 
    }

    
}

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments section where it is unreadable. Instead please edit your original post and post any new code there, making sure to indent it all 4 spaces (by pressing the code button after highlighting it) so it retains its formatting.

Comment: According to the unit test, class Neighbor constructor has two params, a Position and an int value. It should pass the Position param to the super class Occupant constructor. getNeighboringMines returns the int value, getStringRepresentation returns the same int as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MineNeighbour extends Occupant
 {
   private int mines;

  public MineNeighbour(Position neighbour, int mines) { 
    super(neighbour);
    this.mines = mines;
  } 

  public Position getNeighbouringMines() { 
    return mines;
  }

  @Override
  public String getStringRepresenation() { 
    return Integer.toString(mines);
  }
}
```